# Use full width excluding overflow scrollbar with "position: absolute"

Tags: css, google-chrome, overflow, css-position

I would like to have a small red div with full width at a fixed top position, inside another div that has `overflow: scroll`. I hope the jsFiddle makes it clear: http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/2/.

The issue is that the red div is overlapping the scrollbar. I guess `right: 0` means the right hand side of `div.wrapper`; it does not subtract the scrollbar of `div.main`. When I move the `overflow: scroll` into `div.wrapper`, then the red banner has the right size ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/3/)). However, it is not at a fixed position anymore (scrolling down makes the banner scroll up).

How can I achieve the following two things together?

- The red banner is at the fixed position like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/2/).
- The red banner has full width except the scrollbar like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/3/).

I'd like to get this working in Google Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="red-banner"></div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="item">foo</div>
        <div class="item">foo</div>
        <div class="item">foo</div>
        <div class="item">foo</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

div.main {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

div.red-banner {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Why not just position the scrolled element under the bar? Like [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/6/). That's the only simple way I see that you could do this.

Comment: In my real application I have a white-to-transparent gradient instead of red, so as to have a nice effect for text that's scrolling out of the container. That effect is not possible this way unfortunately, because the banner/container are separated.

Comment: @pimvdb, I see, guess you're in for a pickle then (if you want to avoid JS). Maybe you could use styled CSS scrollbars that Chrome supports, that would at least give you a fixed width of it that you could use. Or maybe there is some nice CSS3 hack.

Comment: You could alter the `right` property to match the scrollbar width... Requires JS to make sure that any scrollbar would be correctly measured..

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: Yes, that works, thanks. It's not very satisfying, though. I'll go ahead with that if there won't be any CSS-only answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like this isn't possible with pure CSS, so here's a JavaScript (jQuery) hack:

```
$(function() {
  var $container = $("<div>").css({ height: 1, overflow: "scroll" }).appendTo("body");
  var $child = $("<div>").css({ height: 2 }).appendTo($container);
  window.SCROLLBAR_WIDTH = $container.width() - $child.width();
  $container.remove();
});
```

then:

```
$("div.red-banner").css({
  right: SCROLLBAR_WIDTH
});
```

Comment: No need to use `calc`, just set `right` instead, `right: SCROLLBAR_WIDTH + "px"`.

Comment: @Qtax: Woops, I must have been looking at this for too long. Thanks!

Comment: @Both: I've accepted this answer because it was the only solution without side-effects. I've upvoted you both; thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="banner-wrapper">
        <div class="banner"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="item">foo</div>
    <div class="item">foo</div>
    <div class="item">foo</div>
    <div class="item">foo</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
body {
    padding-top: 30px;
}

div.main {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(white), to(rgba(255,255,255,0)));
}

div.item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

div.scroller {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.banner-wrapper {
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
div.banner {
    height: 20px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(white), to(rgba(255,255,255,0)));;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Development version: http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/13/
Final version: http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/14/

Works with zooming and variable viewport width.
**! BUG**: Scrollbar button from the right top is not accessable/clickable.

Tested in:

- IE6,7,8,9 (windows)
- FF11 (Windows)
- Google Chrome 18 (ubuntu)
- Safari 5.1 (OSX)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the text is now overlapping the banner. The idea was that the banner overlaps the text instead (like in the fiddle). Would you know if that's possible?

Comment: That doesn't fix it, it just places the scrolled element over the bar.

Comment: @pimvdb So finally the CSS only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/9/. I'll now edit my answer with the new infos how to use it. You may need to replace the DataURI to your needs.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I'm using `-webkit-gradient`, which works just great if I plug it into your code: http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/10/. It does require hardcoding of the width of the banner, but oh well.

Comment: @pimvdb Cool! That makes me happy! It should work with variable widths as well, I'll may find out tomorrow.

Comment: @pimvdb, that only works properly you know the width of both the content and the scrollbar. Try zooming in (hit CTRL+PLUS ~5 times) and you will see that the fade doesn't cover the right border of the items. And if you just know the width of the scrollbar then you can just change the `right` value of your original CSS to match the width of the scrollbar.

Comment: @Qtax: Hm yes, it does. I'll post my JavaScript hack which I use for now. @ dop-trois: Sorry for unaccepting, but otherwise everyone will think the question has been solved.

Comment: @dop-trois, this solution can't be perfect since it depends on the width of the scrollbar. But if that's ok for OP then it's alright.

Comment: @Qtax Sorry for that, tested it now like you did, I was happy too early :P @ pimvdb: no problem.

Comment: @Qtax Now working with zooming and variable width (percentage). What about that? http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/14/

Comment: @pimvdb Now working with zooming and variable width (percentage). What about that? http://jsfiddle.net/mCYLm/14/ Sorry can't get this out of my mind ;)

Comment: @dop-trois: Thanks for all your help so far! This time however, the scrollbar is still unusable. Visually, nothing is overlapping the scrollbar, but it is impossible to click the up arrow. That's why I wanted to avoid the overlapping :)

Comment: @pimvdb Ok ^^. Seems to be really impossible to get this 100% bugfree :) Thank you for your answer.