# Creating a floating, collapsible panel using primefaces p:layout

Tags: primefaces

The goal here is to create a panel that is collapsible that also floats independently of the page it is on (so its always visible regardless of where the page scrolls).

I thought that the p:layout would be a good starting point.

In my page I have

```
<div id="tools" class="toolbox">
    <p:layout fullPage="false">
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" collapsed="true" style="padding: initial; border: initial; overflow: hidden;"/>
        <p:layoutUnit position="east" header="Toolbox" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="true">
            <p:tabView id="toolbox-tab">
                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Notes">
                    <p:inputTextarea rows="15" cols="50" />
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</div>
```

And the style associated with the toolbox is:

```
.toolbox {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 360px;
    top: 15em;
}
```

I'm not happy with this as it seems to be a bit of a hack to 'hide' the center panel without scrollbars.

Is this a good solution or can someone suggest a better way to do this?

EDIT:

To be more specific, I'm wondering if there is a different way to replicate the layout format of the p:layout panel along with the collapsible widget button using by Primefaces?

Answer (score 0):

I think I will need more explanations about it, but, could this be something similar ?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                position: relative;
            }
            .tab {
                position: absolute;
                top: 15em;
                right: 0;
                width: 360px;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="tab">
            CONTENT
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then you should decide what to do with the scroll bar issue:

[Use full width excluding overflow scrollbar with "position: absolute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983066/use-full-width-excluding-overflow-scrollbar-with-position-absolute)

Or if you want to limited the height of the < p > , make it scrollable...

Hope it helps 
!

Comment: Thanks for that, but its not really the CSS that i've a problem with. Its more that Primefaces insists on having a center element in the p:layout panel and I'm wondering if there is a different way to replicate the layout format of the p:layout panel along with the collapsible widget button, other than writing my own that is!