# Overflow-y with scrollbar includes width - Centering is off

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where if you have a fixed position element which takes up

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;

overflow-y: auto;
```

I was wondering how to exclude the scrollbar width so the two elements are centered
http://plnkr.co/edit/OJM2SHQ6ytp0sVqFsFU8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[Solution Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983066/use-full-width-excluding-overflow-scrollbar-with-position-absolute):

Seems like this isn't possible with pure CSS, so here's a JavaScript (jQuery) hack:

```
$(function() {
  var $container = $("<div>").css({ height: 1, overflow: "scroll" }).appendTo("body");
  var $child = $("<div>").css({ height: 2 }).appendTo($container);
  window.SCROLLBAR_WIDTH = $container.width() - $child.width();
  $container.remove();
});
```

then:

```
$("div.red-banner").css({
  right: SCROLLBAR_WIDTH
});
```